# Pages not syncing using Browser-sync

Tags: html, google-chrome, browser, browser-sync

Recently i come across the Browser-Sync. I am trying to sync a web page across the devices . Created a folder with 2 files

index.html and style.css

index.html

```
<html>
  <head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>
      Hello world
    </h1>
   </body>
</html>
```

css

```
h1 {
color: white;
background-color:red;
}
```

And in the folder i executed following commands

```
npm install -g browser-sync
```

and

```
browser-sync start --server --files "css/*.css"
```

I got localhost:3000 in browser with index.html . But when i change the color in css its not reflecting any thing. I did manually refresh to the browser. and in other browsers also there is no any sync among others. Is there any thing i need to do additional things. As of now i am not using any external server like apache and all.

Followed this video link
[Browser-syc](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=heNWfzc7ufQ&t=336s)

Answer (score 0):

Try this command

```
browser-sync start --server --directory --file "*"
```

It should sync all files under that directory.

Comment: can you try `browser-sync start --server --directory --files "**/*"` ? This should sync an file you update within your directory. So for example if you have a css folder and index.html within your website directory, then cd into website directory and run that command. Any file that is updated within the website dir should be synced.

Comment: i changed h1 value from Hello world to hello word1. then i refreshed in desktop browser. but in mobile browser still it remains same until i refreshed it manually.  i am not sure what's going wrong. can you please provide the steps you followed

Comment: OK, I think the problem could be in how you input the URL in your phone. When you run that command you see `Access URLs:` and then below that, you you will see a `Local` and an `External` URL. Enter that external URL into your phone. That's all I did, and it syncs automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
browser-sync start -s -f="*"
```

It sounds from your description like your css file is not in the directory you specified. Using the above command should sync everything. If not, perhaps move your css into a /css folder.